# Сменить кодировку CSV файла

Tags: php

папке сайта есть csv файл необходимый для импорта. Но импорт проходит только если файл имеет кодировку utf-8. Пробовал такой способ:

```
function import_correctfunction () {

$f = file_get_contents('imp/price.csv');
    $f = iconv("UTF-8", $f);
file_put_contents('imp/price5.csv', $f);
}
```

Comment: У iconv 3 параметра - из какой, в какую, что

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, а если исходная кодировка неизвестна, есть способ?

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev
 `$f = file_get_contents('imp/price.csv');
 echo mb_detect_encoding($f);
    $f = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($f), "UTF-8", $f);
 //echo $f;
    file_put_contents('imp/price5.csv', $f);`
 специально исходную кодировку utf-8 поставил, кодировку определяет верно, но когда создается новый файл, то он в кодировке win 1251

Comment: А `iconv` нормально срабатывает? Кстати есть ещё вариант `mb_convert_encoding($f, "UTF-8")`

Comment: да кодировка меняется, но файл создается с win 1251

Comment: http://utf8everywhere.org/

Answer (score 0):

Должно вот так сработать ([мануал](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)):

```
$f = mb_convert_encoding($f, "UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1251");
```

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/528015)

Comment: Вот так и знал! Вы вообше ничего не читаете, а один и тот же комент всюду копипастите.Надо пожаловаться, чтобы вас заблокировали.

Comment: А про коммент, это автоматический коммент из очереди проверок, где проверяют такие сомнительные ответы. ;)

Comment: Ну а это в принципе нормальный ответ, хотя к нему можно докапаться.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score -2):

Используй `iconv('UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1251', $f);`

Comment: мда ему нужна utf-8 а не cp-1251

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?