# Поменять кодировку на utf-8 при импорте из csv? (drupal)

Tags: php, drupal, utf-8, csv

Есть csv файл, импорт не проходит, пока я вручную в блокноте не поменяю кодировку на utf-8.
Как сделать, чтобы кодировка менялась автоматически перед созданием материала?

Два разных вопроса, один касался изменения кодировке в файле, другой касается, изменения кодировке, при импорте на сайт средствами Drupal, не затрагивая сам файл.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565373/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0/565396#565396 ваш вопрос

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не следует повторно задавать один и тот же вопрос