# Экспорт HTML таблицы в старый эксель с помощью PHP

Tags: php, excel, csv, export, xls

У кого есть скрипт? Просто в экселе 2011 и старше он открывается кракозябрами. Формат не важен: либо csv, либо xls, главное, чтобы открывался на старых версиях экселя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: libre office скачай и не страдай, это особенность ms office

Comment: @Jean-Claude эти файлы я буду скидывать другим людям, так что нужно универсальное решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла перезапись файла с кодировкой WINDOWS-1251:

```
require "simple_html_dom.php";
$table = $_POST['this_table']; // в этой переменной html-код таблицы

$html = str_get_html($table);

$fp = fopen("table.csv", "w");

foreach ($html->find('tr') as $element) {
    $td = array();
    foreach ($element->find('th') as $row) {
        $td[] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td);

    $td = array();
    foreach ($element->find('td') as $row) {
        $td[] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td);
}

fclose($fp);

$f = file_get_contents("table.csv");
$f = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $f);
$f = mb_convert_encoding($f, "WINDOWS-1251");
file_put_contents("table.csv", $f);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Ты можешь использовать str_get_html https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

include "simple_html_dom.php";
$table = '<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>';

$html = str_get_html($table);



header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.csv');

$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");

foreach($html->find('tr') as $element)
{
    $td = array();
    foreach( $element->find('th') as $row)  
    {
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td);

    $td = array();
    foreach( $element->find('td') as $row)  
    {
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td);
}


fclose($fp);
```

Comment: если текст на русский заменить - всё равно записывается кракозябрами. вы хоть пробовали сами?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565373/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-csv-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0